# Integral of $M^\text{*}-M$ the difference of running maximum and current value with respect to $M^\text{*}$ is 0 for a continuous local martingale $M$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

For $(M_t)$ a continuous local martingale, and $M^\text{*}_t := \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}M_s$ the running maximum of the process, then I'm seeking to prove
$$
\int_0^T (M^\text{*}_s - M_s) \,  \text{d}M^\text{*}_s = 0
$$
Intuitively, this is since $(M^\text{*}_s - M_s) \, \text{d}M^\text{*}_s$ is zero: if we're currently at our maximum then the bracket term is zero, and otherwise $M^\text{*}_s$ is constant near $s$ so $\text{d}M^\text{*}_s$ is $0$.

In a bit more detail, we'll write $P_{t,s} = P_t - P_s$ for $P$ one of the above processes. The integral is equal to the limit in probability of a sequence of partitions $\pi_n$ of $[0,T]$ with mesh tending to 0:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{[s,t]\in \pi_n} (M^\text{*}_{t,s} - M_{t,s})M^\text{*}_{t,s}
$$
and the terms in the sum are 'at the limit' all zero: either we don't reach a new maximum in $[s,t]$, in which case the right term $M^\text{*}_{t,s} = 0$, or we do reach a maximum, in which case "for small $t-s$", we're actively changing the maximum, so that $M^\text{*}_t = M_t$ and $M^\text{*}_s = M_s$ and so  the left difference is $0$ (since $M^\text{*}_{t,s} = M_{t,s}$).

But this last argument depend on choosing a partition after that the outcome has been determined, which can (as with quadratic variation and 2-variation) change the result of the limit. Is the result true? How do you deal with this partition choice?

(I have since also asked this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448853/integral-of-m-text-m-with-respect-to-m-text-is-zero-for-m-text))

Comment: Note https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448853/integral-of-m-text-m-with-respect-to-m-text-is-zero-for-m-text now has an answer.